# Wordpress site showing IP instead of domain

Tags: wordpress

I’ve been trying to change site url from IP address to domain, but unfortunately it doesn’t work, I read many tutorials on this forum with same problem but it didn’t help me. I will briefly describe what I did. First of all, I can’t see site url and home page url label within Settings > General(this is very strange), so I did everything according to this tutorial https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL. When I did that nothing changed. Also, I tried to change siteurl within databse in wp_options table, after I did that, site’s links fell apart and every link started to point on homepage. I don’t have a clue what to do so I am asking for your help.

This is the website:
gongmuse.me

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could be your DNS configuration. I'd suggest searching your database for that ip address and see if it's in any other tables.

Comment: @TimHallman
I did everything according to this tutorial [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean).
Basically I set DO nameservers in my domain's DNS settings. 
I've noticed some strange things while messing around with that problem. When I try to reach for an example gongmuse.me/sl/kontakt (corresponds to http://46.101.247.165/sl/kontakt/) it just redircets me to homepage (http://46.101.247.165/sl/domov).

Comment: Also, when I change "siteurl" and "home" in database table "wp_option" from http://46.101.247.165 to http://gongmuse, everything fall apart and every link starts to point on homepage.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old post but this problem still occures a lot of times so i thought i would add my information here. First of all, changing only wp_options is not enought (if this is the same error as our's was). You also have to change **wp_blogs**. Look at it using `SELECT * FROM wp_blogs;` and then change the according domain field (Step 5.3).

A detailed description on how to solve this issue (also working on multipage). Look out, this changes the database so could potentially break your page. Back up your database before doing this!:

**Tested with Wordpress 4.9.7
!Attention! Those changes are not permantent and will be reset by rebooting!**

---

1) Connect to MySQL (username, password and database name should be 
in your wordpress install directory --> htdocs --> wp-config.php)

```
mysql -u *YOURDBUSERNAME* -p
> *YOURPASSWORD*
```

2) Show all databases to make sure the needed one is there

```
show databases;
```

3) Chose your Database

```
use *DBNAME*;
```

4) Before doing any changes to the database check if this is the correct solution to your Problem

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name="siteurl";
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name="home";
SELECT * FROM wp_blogs;
```

**When we had this Problem, all of those fields were wrongly filled with the IP Address instead of the domain name. I would advise to only proceed if the same is true for you.**

5) Update the wrong entries with your name of choice
5.1) Update Home

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value="http://*YOURDOMAINNAME**" WHERE option_name="home";
```

5.2) Update Siteurl

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value="http://*YOURDOMAINNAME**" WHERE option_name="siteurl";
```

5.3) Update Blogs
    Look at all your Blogs and look where the IP is wrong

```
SELECT * FROM wp_blogs;
```

Change those wrong IPs.
Most Times this should work (!No http://!):

```
UPDATE wp_blogs SET domain="*YOURDOMAINNAME*" WHERE path="/";
```

6) Check your Entries again

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name="siteurl";
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name="home";
SELECT * FROM wp_blogs;
```

**!Attention! Those changes are not permantent and will be reset by rebooting!
Tested with Wordpress 4.9.7**

Answer (score 0):

You could use the rewriteengine via a htaccess to rewrite the URL. But thats only a workaround.

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules

+You can check if a rewriting is already there.

Comment: Can you be more specific because I am little bit confused. htacces purpose is for an example if you have example.com/fizz/bazz and you want to change it to example.com/foo, isn't it?